# Is slicing really slower in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, python-3.4

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37052139/6292850) and my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37055026/6292850) got me thinking about this peculiar difference between Python 2.7 and Python 3.4. Take the simple example code:

```
import timeit
import dis

c = 1000000
r = range(c)
def slow():
    for pos in range(c):
        r[pos:pos+3]

dis.dis(slow)

time = timeit.Timer(lambda: slow()).timeit(number=1)
print('%3.3f' % time)
```

In Python 2.7, I consistently get `0.165~` and for Python 3.4 I consistently get `0.554~`. The only significant difference between the disassemblies is that Python 2.7 emits the [`SLICE+3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-SLICE+3) byte code while Python 3.4 emits [`BUILD_SLICE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_SLICE) followed by [`BINARY_SUBSCR`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_SLICE). Note that I've eliminated the candidates for potential slowdown from the other question, namely strings and the fact that `xrange` doesn't exist in Python 3.4 (which is supposed to be similar to the latter's `range` class anyways).

Using `itertools'` `islice` yields nearly identical timings between the two, so I highly suspect that it's the slicing that's the cause of the difference here.

Why is this happening and is there a link to an authoritative source documenting change in behavior?

EDIT: In response to the answer, I have wrapped the `range` objects in `list`, which did give a noticeable speedup. However as I increased the number of iterations in `timeit` I noticed that the timing differences became larger and larger. As a sanity check, I replaced the slicing with `None` to see what would happen.

500 iterations in `timeit`.

```
c = 1000000
r = list(range(c))
def slow():
    for pos in r:
        None
```

yields `10.688` and `9.915` respectively. Replacing the for loop with `for pos in islice(r, 0, c, 3)` yields `7.626` and `6.270` respectively. Replacing `None` with `r[pos]` yielded `20~` and `28~` respectively. `r[pos:pos+3]` yields `67.531` and `106.784` respectively.

As you can see, the timing differences are huge. Again, I'm still convinced the issue is not directly related to `range`.

Comment: Were you using `range` or `xrange` in Python 2?

Comment: Try again, with `r = list(range(c))`.

Comment: Python 3 `range` and Python 2 `xrange` objects are not similar in this context.  Python 3 `range` objects support slicing, Python 2 `xrange` objects do not support slicing.

Comment: @cdarke In this case it's irrelevant since neither the linked question nor I used xrange. I only mentioned it incase somebody were to bring it up.

Answer (score 10):

On Python 2.7, you're iterating over a list and slicing a list. On Python 3.4, you're iterating over a `range` and **slicing a `range`**.

When I run a test with a list on both Python versions:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('x[5:8]', setup='x = list(range(10))'))
```

I get [0.243554830551 seconds on Python 2.7](http://ideone.com/S8Th1n) and [0.29082867689430714 seconds on Python 3.4](http://ideone.com/Pf9Nst), a much smaller difference.

---

The performance difference you see after eliminating the `range` object is much smaller. It comes primarily from two factors: addition is a bit slower on Python 3, and Python 3 needs to go through `__getitem__` with a slice object for slicing, while Python 2 has `__getslice__`.

I wasn't able to replicate the timing difference you saw with `r[pos]`; you may have had some confounding factor in that test.

Comment: Increasing the number of iterations starts to show bigger and bigger gaps in the timing differences. `1.352` and `2.171` respectively for 10 iterations. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: @user6292850: How are you running that test?

Comment: I'm merely increasing the number parameter in `timeit`, and running `python test.py` followed by `python3 test.py`.

Comment: @user6292850: I ran some tests and isolated the primary contributors to the remaining performance difference. My tests with `r[pos]` only showed a 10% runtime difference, unlike your 40% runtime difference, though.

Comment: @user6292850 which `test.py` are you testing? Yours in the question or the one in this answer? Let's test the same thing. I suggest using this format: `python -m timeit -s "r = list(range(1000))" "for pos in range(1000): r[pos:pos+3]"`. Why would you not use the default number of iterations of 1000000?